# What is the origin and meaning of a -yr ending?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

Some words in the English language end with a "`-yr`", such as, satyr, martyr, or zephyr.

What is the origin of the `-yr` ending?
What is the meaning of the `-yr` ending?

I have searched the etymology, and all I could find is that it is Greek. That does not answer my question. I want to know why it is `-yr` and not, for example, `-er` or `-or`. Does the `-yr` have any special significance?

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy I figured as much seeing as the words are based from Greek. I will revise my question some. I want to know what the '-yr' means exactly. Where the -yr originates from, not just the language it is from.

Comment: If you check the etymologies you will see that there's no consistent origin.

Comment: @HotLicks As I said, I did check that. I was hoping that someone, like ermanen below, would be able to tell me more. Also, if you can, how is this question off-topic? I thought etymology of English words was on-topic here?

Comment: @ermanen Thanks! That is exactly what I was wanting to know. If the question was open, I would accept this.

Comment: the -yr ending seems to have the same origins as -er and -or. In matyr, "mart-" is probably ultimately < the same Indo-European base as classical Latin "morī" to die - martyr - one who dies.

Comment: @Andrew: I've voted to reopen. You can also add the etymology of words from etymonline.com so the question would have a better chance to be re-opened.

Comment: Because that's the way the Romans chose to spell those Greek words in Latin. This question has almost nothing to do with English since those words are virtually unchanged from their Latin origins.

Answer (score 2):

The short "y" represents the sound of "i" before "r" in the words *zephyr, martyr, satyr*. You can see "y" representing the value of short "i" in other words like *analysis, crypt, etymology, Egypt, myth, oxygen, pterodactyl, system* etc. derived from Greek but borrowed through Latin or French.

The common pattern in *zephyr, martyr, satyr* can be traced back to their ultimate Ancient Greek origin which has a similar ending and and the letter upsilon (υ).

The relevant part from the etymology of the words from *OED*:

- *zephyr*: < classical Latin *Zephyrus* < ancient Greek *Ζέϕυρος*
- *martyr*: < post-classical Latin *martyr* < Hellenistic Greek *μάρτυρ*
- *satyr*:     Partly < classical Latin *satyrus* and partly (in later use) < Middle French *satire, satyre* (French *satyre*) (late 14th cent.) < classical Latin *satyrus* < Ancient Greek *σάτυρος*

The letter “y” was a readoption in Latin of the Greek upsilon (υ), and was used for Greek borrowings.